# Make v-text-field required based on v-radio choice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am new to front end specially vue
in my register page, I have this v-radio-group

```
<v-radio-group
  v-model="row"
    row
  >
  <v-radio
    label="personal"
    value="false"
    data-cy="input-individual"
  />
  <v-radio
    label="company"
    value="true"
  />
</v-radio-group>
```

and I want to make the v-text-field phone number and company name required if the user choose company

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="name"
  label="* fullname"
  :rules="requirerule"
  required
  data-cy="input-name"
/>

<v-text-field
  v-model="telephone"
    label="phone number"
    data-cy="input-telephone"
/>
<v-text-field
  v-model="companyname"
  label="company name"
  data-cy="input-companyname"
/>
```

Does anyone has a solution what should I do, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the value of your `v-radio-group` to a model `isCompany`

```
<v-radio-group v-model="isCompany" row>
  <v-radio
    label="personal"
    :value="false"
  />
  <v-radio
    label="company"
    :value="true"
  />
</v-radio-group>
```

Then in your `<script>` `methods` section you need to define the validation method and set a rule to validate the text field based on the value of `isCompany`

```
data(): {
  return {
    // ... 
    isCompany: false,
  }
  methods: {
    // .....
    requiredIfCompany: function(value) { 
      if(this.isCompany) {
        return !!value || 'Required.';
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Then on your `v-text-field` you need to set the rules

```
<v-text-field v-model="telephone"
    :rules=[requiredIfCompany]
    label="phone number"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

It should work fine as long as you use,

```js
<v-text-field
  v-model="telephone"
    label="phone number"
    data-cy="input-telephone"
    :required="row"
/>
```

Also your radio buttons are passing value as string in props, it will work as Boolean as long as you change the radio value props as follow,

```js
<v-radio
    label="company"
    :value="true"
  />
```

I have just made your `value` to `:value` so instead of reading it as string it execute the value which will be considered as Boolean.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but it doesn't appear that the following text field will be required when I apply your solution

Comment: and I cannot change the value in v-radio, it it change I need to make quite big change in the system

Comment: `v-text-field` doesn't have props `required`. You need to use validation rule as stated in the docs. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#validation